# can supply stream input to Open3.capture3 in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, stdin, spawn

i know i can supply a String for stdin input to `Open3.capture3` via

```
Open3.capture3 some_cmd, stdin_data: some_string
```

but is it possible to provide a stream-like input, like from an open file?

something like

```
Open3.capture3 some_cmd, in: File.open(filepath)
```

i get that `capture3` passes it's options to `Process.spawn` and i've read the documentation at

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Process.html#method-c-spawn

but i don't really understand it in the context of supplying input, and haven't been able to find any relevant examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`popen3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3) instead of `capture3`, according to Open3 documentation.

Note that, for your example, you will probably have to spawn a thread to read input from your stream and redirect it to the one provided by open3, depending on where your stream comes from.

Comment: yeah, right now it's working with `popen3`. i was asking specifically about `capture3`. if it's not possible with `capture3` i can just keep using `popen3`.

Answer (score 0):

I have read this on the subject of STDIN redirection on http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Process.html#method-c-spawn:

```
pid = spawn(command, :in=>"/dev/null")
```

The documentation of `Open3` says that you can use the attributes that `spawn` defines, so you should be able to use `in` in `capture*` and `popen3`, too, though I have tested this. If it does not work, there is still `spawn`.